# 'Mirror' database connection using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

Now before I start I just want to say that I have absolutely no idea if this is possible.

---

**The Question**
I am used to managing databases on my computer using Sequel Pro, and that is what I have done for the past few years with my Linode VPS. I recently purchased iPage hosting to store some static content and I wanted to set up a database to keep an easy archive of it. Having created the database and set up the access details I wrote a basic PHP script for it.

I wanted to connect via Sequel Pro, but with a lot of shared hosting they don't seem to let you do this for security reasons. **My question is, would it be possible to write a script that you connected to the same way as a database, but which processed all your requests to the database before returning it?** If it is possible, how would you go about it, and if it's not, why?

Comment: Is SSH allowed? Cause then you could just tunnel...

Comment: @Wrikken Could you elaborate?

Comment: _IF_ you have SSH access to the hosting platform, you can bind a local port (on your end) to the mysql port at the other end, and just connect to that.

Comment: @Wrikken Nope, no SSH access either :(

Comment: That's a pity. The point is while it's technically possible to implement the mysql protocol in PHP (but a big project and undesirable), even then random listening ports would most likely be blocked by your current hosting. If the only ports allowed are ports implmenting the HTTP protocol, I fear there's no way your client app can be made to speak HTTP. The only solutions with merit I can see are either a package like `phpmyadmin` on the server, or switching hosts.

Comment: If your hosting supports remote mysql , which it should you can directly connect.
not sure about yours, but hostgator do allow this.

Comment: My host does not not allow remote MySQL, which is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

SQLyog has php proxy, and it is generally one of the methods for connecting to mysql databases which are bound to localhost. Also, some cPanel hostings have an option where you can specify external IP which can connect to the database, have you asked the support if there is such an options?

In SQLyog, feature where they use php proxy is called HTTP Tunnel. Maybe there exists something like that for Sequel ?

https://static.webyog.com/docs/SQLyog/HTTP_Tunneling_SQLyog_MySQL_Client.html